# Objective-C UIViewController Category is causing Error NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, categories, statusbar

I am using a Category to add functionality to my ViewControllers. When the function from the category is run I get an error `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7970ebf0`. To test out the function I'm calling, I originally had the code within my viewDidLoad where I am calling the added function and it worked fine, so I don't think it is a problem with the function itself. So here is my code for the category and where I call it. Am implementing the Category incorrectly?

Here is "UIViewController+StatusBar.h"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIViewController (StatusBar)

-(void) addStatusBarBackground;

@end
```

Here is "UIViewController+StatusBar.m"

```
#import "UIViewController+StatusBar.h"

@implementation UIViewController (StatusBar)

-(void) addStatusBarBackground(){
    //for making the background of the UIStatus bar black
    UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, [[self view] bounds].size.width, 22)];
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:statusBarView];
}

@end
```

And then I call the function in viewDidLoad of my controller after including UIViewController+StatusBar.h like so
`[self addStatusBarBackground];` This is where the error happens, when this is called.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You need to provide specific details about the crash. What is the actual error? Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: I edited my question a little bit, but the crash happens when `[self addStatusBarBackground]` is called, and the only error I get is the one in the second sentence of my question.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: One tip is to add a exception breakpoint in Xcode right panel under breakpoints tab klick the '+' sign in the left bottom corner and add exception breakpoint then a breakpoint will be placed where the exception happens.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the useful comments. I will try those things out.

Comment: The error you pointed out is not the entire error message. We can't guess what's the issue without it.

Comment: I believe I changed it to the correct error message, but I also just figured out the problem. I didn't have the target memberships selected on the right panel so that the extended files were actually included

Comment: That method declaration is wrong: `-(void) addStatusBarBackground(){`

Comment: Your right, no parenthesis, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. It ended out to be nothing to do with the category. The category was implemented correctly except for the declaration `-(void) addStatusBarBackground()`. The parenthesis needed to be deleted. The problem was that I did not select the target memberships that my app has on the right panel in my UIViewController+StatusBar.m file. So the file was not being compiled for my project. I guess its kind of like it wasn't included. I haven't dealt with target memberships before so that was why I was unaware of the problem. Thanks for the comments helping me figure out the answer!